# ServiceStack.Redis Cache Cleared when application restarted

Tags: servicestack.redis

I am using redis for Caching, but am also using ICacheClient in one of my services to write and read directly from the Cache using Get and Set etc.

Redis is set to persist the values to disk.  So if I shut Redis down and restart it again, the cached data is there.  However, if I run my servicestack services in debug mode and stop the website and restart it again, servicestack clear the redis cache on the first call that is made to the servicestack service.  How can I switch this off, or is it a bug. The items in the cache should not expire and when checking the individual items in the cache, it is set not to expire, so it is not that it is expiring, but that servicestack seems to flush the database on first call after restart.

```
        public ICacheClient CacheClient { get; set; }

        public object Get(KeyValues request)
        {

            var value = CacheClient.Get<object>(request.Key);

            var response = new KeyValuesResponse { Key = request.Key, Value       = value };
            return value;
        }

        public void Put(KeyValuesRecord request)
        {
           if (request.Key != null)
           { 
                CacheClient.Set(request.Key,request.Value);
           }
        }

        public void Post(KeyValuesRecord request)
        {
            CacheClient.Set(request.Key, request.Value);
        }

        public void Delete(KeyValues request)
        {
            CacheClient.Remove(request.Key);
        }
```

When I call the first Get with for e.g. the url : http://localhost:4099/api/KeyValues/mykey

The whole redis db(0) is cleared out.

Comment: Not seeing this behavior when using SS with Redis or anywhere in the code where it's flushing Redis automatically (inc in DebugMode). Are you explicitly calling `*FlushAll()` or `Clear()` anywhere?  e.g. in Sessions or AuthUserRepositories?

Comment: No, not at all.  I just use set and get in a Put and Get Service.  I have tested this by adding keys and values in the default database db(0) separate from servicestack using the console.  If I then start my project and go to a to get a value http://localhost:4099/api/KeyValues/mykey then the whole db(0) is cleared out.

Comment: Can't repro it or imagine what's causing it, if you can send me a link to a stand-alone GitHub repo that reproduces the issue I can investigate further. I'm assuming you're using the latest v4.0.40 release?

Comment: Using v4.0.38.  Will upload GitHub repo..will take a while.